# Show create table not showing full output in hive

Tags: hive

In hive, when typed - show create table table_name does not show the full output especially when the table has many columns specified. In ordert to show the whole output what command should be added??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using hive or beeline shell? It might be related with interface that you used. Especially shell tools might be limited for long results.
Could you try it from Hue or a graphical desktop tool like Dbeaver?